# Question structure for possessive pronoun

Tags: pronouns, possessives

> My paper is ready.

I want to make this sentence into a question. In my view, it would be

> Is my paper ready?

Is it correct according to English grammar? It might be correct but I need a reference.

Comment: Who are casting -ve vote? Can you please explain ?

Comment: I agree that the title of this question is not the best. It doesn't matter if there's a possessive pronoun or not. "The paper," "This paper," "My paper," etc. would all behave the same way in a question.

Comment: Before going to ask question, I searched a lot. But fail to get any reference. I made this sentence into question from my common understanding. Can you please suggest me some title then I will edit the title. @Mixolydian

Comment: Are you confused about the phrasing of yes/no questions that have possessive pronouns in the noun phrases, as opposed to yes/no questions in general? If so, then your title is ok. If you're asking about yes/no questions in general, you might want to change the title. But it sounds like you understand how to form such questions intuitively, based on your guess above about how to make the statement into a question.

Comment: Would you explain a little bit why you're unsure that you are correctly transforming the sentence into a question? If the sentence was "The report is complete." (without the possessive) would you have the same trouble? I think if you [edit] to include why the possessive pronoun seems special to you, we may be able to take this off hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes- definitely correct.

EDIT: to add some explanation: if you have a sentence of the form "**[Noun Phrase] [to be] [Adjective]**" - as in your example, "My paper [NP] is [to be] ready [Adj]," to turn it into a yes/no question, your guess about how is correct: "**[to be] [Noun Phrase] [Adjective]?**"

Examples:

Statement: The cat is orange. Question: Is the cat orange?

Statement: This exercise is bad. Question: Is this exercise bad?

Statement: John is angry. Question: Is John angry?

Statement: My skin is itchy. Question: Is my skin itchy?

Statement: Your coat is nice. Question: Is your coat nice?

Statement: That movie is scary. Question: Is that movie scary?

Statement: She is funny. Question: Is she funny?

Statement: It is pointless. Question: Is it pointless?

Comment: Any reference ?